# Can I script different /etc/hosts overrides to have DNS resolution change depending on my network location?

Tags: macos, network, dns

I've used to have some entries in `/etc/hosts` in some network locations, but they must not be present in other network locations. Currently, I've to edit `/etc/hosts` manually if I switch between those network locations.

Unfortunately, additional DNS entries can't be configured via network locations on macOS.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for a solution for this myself for a while, but after I moved to a new house, and got a new modem (Zyxel VMG8825-T50), I discovered that it has the capability to maintain a list of 'DNS entries' and I can simply map the URL of a website I'm hosting in my LAN, e.g. `www.example.com` to `192.168.1.100`.

If your modem doesn't support that, or you can't change that configuration, you'd have to run a DNS server on the networks where you want a different IP address for a certain host. [Here](https://superuser.com/a/444216/442468) is some more information about this on our sister site SuperUser.